# set cursor position in textarea at end once user clicked on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Move caret to last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715762/javascript-move-caret-to-last-character)

I am working on text area using jquery, to provide good UI validation.
Currently I stuck at -

Once user click in text area I want to set cursor position forcefully at end.
Please provide me some jquery solutions so resolve this ?

Thanks in advance
-Pravin