# How to place cursor at end of text in textarea when tabbed into

Tags: javascript, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Move caret to last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715762/javascript-move-caret-to-last-character)

I have a standard textarea with some text in it. I'm looking for a way to have the cursor automatically be placed at the end of the existing text so a user can simply start typing to add more text. This should happen whenever the textarea becomes active such as when a user tabs into it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

I've answered this before: [Javascript: Move caret to last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715762/javascript-move-caret-to-last-character/4716021#4716021)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghAB9/6/

Code:

```
<textarea id="test">Some text</textarea>
```

```js
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("test");

textarea.onfocus = function() {
    moveCaretToEnd(textarea);

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        moveCaretToEnd(textarea);
    }, 1);
};
```

Comment: Can you explain why `window.setTimeout` fixed the problem in Chrome? It worked for me but I don't understand the logic behind

Comment: @HP: The problem in Chrome (at least in the version that was current when this answer was written) is that it fires the `focus` event and then displays the caret, meaning that the browser only displays the caret after `moveCaretToEnd()` has been called. The `window.setTimeout()` call allows the browser to display the caret first and then JavaScript moves it into place.

Answer (score 4):

You need to listen to the focus event in the text area for example :

```
<textarea onfocus="setCursorAtTheEnd(this,event)"/>
```

And then in your javascript code:

```
function setCursorAtTheEnd(aTextArea,aEvent) {
    var end=aTextArea.value.length;
    if (aTextArea.setSelectionRange) {
        setTimeout(aTextArea.setSelectionRange,0,[end,end]);  
    } else { // IE style
        var aRange = aTextArea.createTextRange();
        aRange.collapse(true);
        aRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        aRange.moveStart('character', end);
        aRange.select();    
    }
    aEvent.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that the default action of `aEvent` is inhibited. This prevents the browser from selecting all the whole text (for example in firefox)
Not sure if this code is cross browser compatible.

Comment: The general approach is correct (apart from you have `text` where you meant `aTextArea` on the second line), but it won't work in Chrome.

Comment: @Tim : You are right, I've edited the code thanks :). Regarding chrome (and perhaps other webkit based browser), do you know the equivalent function for setting the selection (or does this method fail for another reason) ?

Comment: @sitifensys: The method works in Chrome but the `focus` event fires too early and the browser moves the cursor after the event handler has placed it at the end. You can get round this by using a brief timer.

Comment: @Tim Down I've edited the code again and added a setTimout call :). But a question still remains, isn't preventDefault() supposed to cancel the default action of the event in chrome ? or did I misread the DOM specification ?

Comment: No, you haven't misread the spec, but it appears to be impossible to prevent a textarea from receiving focus by using `preventDefault()` in Chrome (or indeed Firefox).