# jQuery move cursor to end of text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textinput

Currently I have an input box which has the value "Current Website"

When they click it I run this function:

```
function clearMeHttp(formfield) {
    if (formfield.defaultValue == formfield.value) {
        formfield.value = "http://";
    }
};
```

It works fine if you click into the box, but if you tab into the box it just highlights the word "http://" which defeats the purpose of it unless they hit the right arrow key which I want to avoid.

Thanks!

Here's the other code: `<input onblur="restoreMe(this)" onfocus="clearMeHttp(this)" type="text" class="fade" name="website" value="Current website">`

restoreMe just fades default value back in gently with jquery

Comment: on which event you have called this function?

Comment: `<input onblur="restoreMe(this)" onfocus="clearMeHttp(this)" type="text" class="fade" name="website" value="Current website">`

Comment: i m not sure but you have to use setselectionrange fucntion for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit, but uses jquery events instead of inline html.

Full script used:

```
var defaultVal = 'Current website';
$(function() {

    $('.urlCheck').focus(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "http://" || $(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == defaultVal) {
            $(this).val('http://');
            $(this).select(false);

        }
    });

    $('.urlCheck').keyup(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "http://" || $(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == defaultVal) {
            $(this).val('http://');
        }
    });

    $('.urlCheck').blur(function(e) {
        $(this).val(defaultVal);
    });

});
```

Working Link : http://jsfiddle.net/29gks/6/

**The *keyup* event is the override for Chrome and Safari**

Comment: Let me know if it's working for you.. busy looking at a working deselect solution for Chrome/Safari.

Comment: is it possible just to imitate the right arrow function once they tab into the box and after it displays the http://? I dont mind if they can delete it or any of that (if they really wanted to they could backspace it). as long as its not highlighted im happy. disabling tab isnt ideal

Comment: :) That is actually what I am looking at currently. Will let you know ASAP.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Using a keyup event and setting the value fixed the Chrome/Safari issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't use jquery so I follow you.

script:

```
function clearMeHttp(formfield) {
    if (formfield.defaultValue == formfield.value) { 
         formfield.value="";        
         formfield.style.padding="0 0 0 40";
         document.getElementById("http").style.display="block";
    }
};
```

html:

```
<label id="http" style="float:left;position:absolute;display:none;">http://</label>
<input onblur="restoreMe(this)" onfocus="clearMeHttp(this)" type="text" class="fade" name="website" value="Current website">
```

That catch your requirement but may be not the way you want

Comment: sorry, i tagged jquery because I thought there may be a function built into there to make it easy. unfortunately I'm already using a lot of labels so it would have to be without that method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setSelectionRange()` (or `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`) on most browsers and some `TextRange` shenanigans on IE < 9.

Here's my previous answer to the same question: [How to place cursor at end of text in textarea when tabbed into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003300/how-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-textarea-when-tabbed-into/6003829#6003829)