# How do I set cursor focus to end of input after using keyup function

Tags: jquery, focus, textinput, cursor-position

I got this script off 9lessons.info and it is supposed to auto suggest friends when you type an @ symbol.

The Problem is after getting name from database, the curser points to the beginning of the text area. I want  to focus on input text field such that the cursor is placed at the end of the text.

Source Code:

PHP code

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if($_POST){
    $q=$_POST['searchword'];
    $q=str_replace("@","",$q);
    $q=str_replace(" ","%",$q);
    $sql_res=mysql_query("select * from user_data where fname like '%$q%' or lname like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)){
        $fname=$row['fname'];
        $lname=$row['lname'];
        $img=$row['img'];
        $country=$row['country'];

    ?>
    <div class="display_box" align="left">
    <!--<img src="user_img/<?php echo $img; ?>" class="image"/>-->
    <a href="#" class='addname' title='<?php echo $fname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $lname; ?>'>
    <?php echo $fname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $lname; ?> </a><br/></div>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Facebook like Tag Friends</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

$("#contentbox").live("keyup",function() 
{
var content=$(this).text();
var go= content.match(start);
var name= content.match(word);
var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

if(go.length>0)
{
$("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
$("#display").slideUp('show');
$("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
if(name.length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "boxsearch.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

}
}
return false();
});

$(".addname").live("click",function() 
{
var username=$(this).attr('title');
var old=$("#contentbox").html();
var content=old.replace(word,""); 
$("#contentbox").html(content);
var E="<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+username+"</a>";
$("#contentbox").append(E);
$("#display").hide();
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#contentbox").focus();
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h3>Tutorial link <a href="http://9lessons.info">Click Here</a></h3>
<h2>Eg: 9lessons blog @sri</h2>
<div id="xxx"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true"> 
</div>
<div id='display'>
</div>
<div id="msgbox">
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267913/jquery-move-cursor-to-end-of-text-input  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953192/jquery-textbox-cursor-to-end-of-text    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element hope these might help u

Comment: i didn get... :( please help me to set it in this code