# Changing value of textarea onclick puts caret in a weird position, but in IE only

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a text area which on page load has default text of "List". On focus this text is removed and replaced with "-". I would like the caret position to be after the "-", this works in chrome, opera, FF and safari but in IE the caret initially is in the correct place, but then after a slight pause jumps to before the "-".

Here's the code I've been using:

```
    input.onfocus = function(){
        if(this.value == 'List') {
            this.value = '-';
        }
    }
```

I have tried using the `onclick` event as well, using tricks like `this.value = this.value` after the "-" is inserted but none of this works. If anyone could provide me with a work around I will be extremely grateful.

Thank-you!

edit:
Kierans answer below solved the problem, perfect! An if statement added to his code stops chrome throwing a little error:

```
    input.onclick = function(){
        if(this.value == 'List') {
            this.value = "-";
            if (this.createTextRange) {
                var range = this.createTextRange();
                var caretPos = this.value.length;
                range.move('character', caretPos);
                range.select();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a simple code snippet in Firefox,Chrome and IE. Same issue i am facing in IE so that we can set the caret position with some code snippet that as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="List" onfocus="changeValue(this);"/>
function changeValue(e){
    if(e.value == "List"){
            e.value = "-";
           var range = e.createTextRange();
            var caretPos = e.value.length;
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
    }
}
```

So, above code is working fine.

For reference see the url : http://jsfiddle.net/J72xB/1/

NOTE: Above code is tested in FireFox6,Chrome,IE9.Hope this will help you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example! I made a slight alteration to your code as chrome does not like createTextRange(), will post as edit to question!

Comment: `createTextRange()` is IE (and possibly Opera) only. Use `setSelectionRange()` or the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties in all browsers except IE < 9.

Answer (score 1):

The following is adapted from my answer to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003829/96100). It works in all major browsers and works around an issue in Chrome that prevents the caret being positioned in the `focus` event:

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

input.onfocus = function() {
    if (input.value == 'List') {
        input.value = '-';
    }

    moveCaretToEnd(input);

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        moveCaretToEnd(input);
    }, 1);
};
```