# How to activate text input on a button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to activate a text input using a button. 
My function is like this.

```
function showHide4()
{
 document.getElementById('snack').readOnly=false;
 document.getElementById('snack').style.backgroundColor"#ffffff";   
}
```

This function makes text input writable and changes background to white, but it gets activated only after I click on it.

**Note:- My idea of activated text input is cursor(|) blinking in it.**  maybe activated is not a correct word for it but I don't know what else to call it.

**EDIT:-** I tried focus(), Problem in using focus() is Default value in my text input is getting selected automatically, which is not what I want, I want to put cursor(|) after that value.

Comment: it is called focus.
.focus()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, I think `focus()` is what you are looking for:

```
function showHide4() {
    var el = document.getElementById('snack');
    el.readOnly = false;
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    el.focus();
    el.value = el.value;
};
```

To do what you want you need to cheat a bit, just reset (set again) the value of the input and it will work as you want.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qjvNP/)**

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe, great!

Comment: but the problem is value in the text input is getting selected automatically.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe, did you see the demo?

Comment: my bad man didn't notice the link, and yes your demo is working which means i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
function showHide4()
{
 document.getElementById('snack').readOnly = false;
 document.getElementById('snack').style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";  
 document.getElementById('snack').focus(); 
}
```

This will work!

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003300/how-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-textarea-when-tabbed-into). I think this will help you to place cursor pointer at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How to activate text input on a button click in React

This is how i did it using react.

```
export default function App() {
  function showHide4() {
    var el = document.getElementById("snack");
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#fdd";
    el.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" id="other" value="100" readonly="true" />
      <input type="text" id="snack" />

      <button type="button" onClick={showHide4} id="button">
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```