# Textarea cursor not set at end point

Tags: html, cordova, textarea, samsung-mobile

I am developing a phonegap application, there is a textarea on a page with some predefined value. When I tap on that textarea the pointer moves to the start point not at the end point.
This issue i am facing is only in Samsung S3 device. I tested it on other devices like Moto G on which it is working fine.

Comment: Google:"textarea set cursor position to end" -> First result -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003300/how-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-textarea-when-tabbed-into/6003829#6003829

Comment: @Sithys I already tried it, not working for me.

Comment: Than post your code or should we guess what you wrote?