# How to send the 'ctrl+end' key to <textarea> element so the cursor lands after last character

Tags: javascript

(send: that is to emulate typing these keys as user would normally do it)

I know this metod element.value = element.value, but I think it might be slow for textareas that have huge amount of data in them, like wikis etc.

Comment: I would suggest you using jQuery if possible to achieve this. jQuery provides with really good support to this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this SO question: [Javascript: Move caret to last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715762/javascript-move-caret-to-last-character)