# jQuery .focus() works differently in each browser. How to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

When I try to do `.focus()` I expect to set focus on input element and to see cursor after last character of the value. And I see it in IE.

In safari/chrome input gets focus and all text is selected.
In firefox/opera input gets focus, but cursor is in the beginning.

What could I do to prevent that and get correct behavior for all browsers?

An example is here: http://jsbin.com/ozojol/edit#javascript,html

PS. `focus().val('').val(value)` method doesn't work in IE... What other workarounds exist?

Comment: What version of Firefox, and on what OS? Firefox 13.0.1 on Windows 7 puts the cursor after the value.

Comment: OSX, FireFox 13.0 :) I will try 13.0.1 later, but it works differently in other browsers :) And I'm trying to find solution how to prevent that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716021/96100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the input's `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties in most browsers and some nasty `TextRange` stuff in IE < 9. Here's some code adapted from [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716021/96100).

Demo: http://jsbin.com/azapuy

Code:

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

var input = $('#i')[0];
input.focus();
moveCaretToEnd(input);
```

Comment: Works in FF 16 - nice! You have to be careful to call moveCaretToEnd with the actual dom element (as shown above), not the jQuery object. The latter does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great lightweight plugin to move the caret to the end of the content within your element. **[jQuery Caret](https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uksXG/)**

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox 3.6. Does work in: IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome 19 and Safari 4. Moves to first position in: Opera 11.

Comment: @rcdmk I have updated my answer. **[jQuery Caret](https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret)** will tackle the issue.

Comment: jQuery Caret doesn't work in IE8. maybe others, haven't tried.

Comment: @InviS [Jquery Caret](https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret) works in IE8 (My OS: Windows XP). Did you test it w/ this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uksXG/)**?

Comment: @Fari I've tested it in BrowserStack :) OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The only common behavior is the `select()`, that selects the input text in all major browsers (can't confirm if it works in all browsers).