# Setting focus to the end of textbox using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, textbox, focus

I have written below code to set focus to the end of text in the textbox :

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('txtFilter');
textbox.focus(); 
textbox.value = textbox.value;
```

*But I am facing a problem here. When i keep typing fastly, newly typed characters are not appearing and it is displaying the old value again and again. So I have to wait after pressing each key, then it works fine.*

I found another piece of code to achieve this:

```
if (textbox.createTextRange) {               
var FieldRange = textbox.createTextRange();            
FieldRange.moveStart('character', textbox.value.length);
FieldRange.collapse();
FieldRange.select();
return false;
}
```

But when I tried this, I am getting error - Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e sometimes. Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716021/96100

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#txtFilter').focus(); //focus using jQuery (browser indipendent)
$('#txtFilter').caretToEnd(); // move position to the end
```

Unfortunately you need a plugin https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907